# How to include subsections in tex4ebook TOC?

Tags: tex4ebook

This MWE properly displays subsections in the TOC but when I create an epub with `tex4ebook -l main.tex` the TOC only goes as deep as the sections. How can I make it include subsections?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1.2}
\section{Section 1.2}
\subsection{Subsection 1.2.1}

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{Section 2.1}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1.2}
\section{Section 2.2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2.1}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2.2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in line with Memoir's behaviour, which doesn't include `\subsections` in TOC either. You can request them with this config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{tableofcontents*}{chapter,section,subsection}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This configuration lists types of sectioning commands that should be listed in `\tableofcontents`. If you want to include starred versions of sections, use `like` prefix, for example `likesection`.

This is the resulting TOC:

[image]

Note that subsection numbers aren't included, because these are not saved in TOC metadata by Memoir.